# code works fine but the console print cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

[image]

guys i create a function to limit the user`s upload images everything works fine but the problem that
i got an Error on the console (Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client)

and when i copy the whole code of the function note(! not the function itself ) . on the controllers file i didnt get the error however ( its the same code and same everything
but the code is too long so it looks bad
please check the image before looking into the code

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const appError = require('./appError')
module.exports.validateHadith = (req,res,next)=>{
     
    const hadithSchema = Joi.object({
       Hadith: Joi.object({
           narrator: Joi.string().required(),
           description:Joi.string().required().min(15),
           hadith:Joi.string().required().min(15),
       }).required()
   })
   const {error} = hadithSchema.validate(req.body);
   if(error){
       const msg = error.details.map(el=>el.message).join(',')
      throw new appError(msg,400)
      } else{
          next()
      }
   };
   
   module.exports.reviewValidation = (req,res,next) => {
       
       const reviewJoiSchema = Joi.object({
           review: Joi.object({
               comment: Joi.string().required(),
               rating: Joi.number().required(),
           }).required()
       })
       const {error} = reviewJoiSchema.validate(req.body);
       if(error) {
           const msg = error.details.map(el=>el.message).join(',')
           throw new appError(msg,400)
       } else {
           next()
       }
       }

       module.exports.imageValidation = (req,res,next) => {
       const imageSchema = Joi.array().min(1).max(6).required()
       const {error} = imageSchema.validate(req.files)
       if(error) {
        const msg = error.details.map(el=>el.message).join(',')
        throw new appError(msg,400)
       } else{
           next()
       }
    }
       module.exports.imageEditValidation = async (updatedHadith,images,req,res,id) => {
        const length = updatedHadith.images.length 
        const max = 6    
        if(images.length+length <= max) {
          updatedHadith.images.push(...images) 
          await updatedHadith.save()
          console.log(updatedHadith)
          
        } else{
          req.flash('error','Sorry you can`t have more than 6 images')
          return res.redirect(`/hadith/${id}`)
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the validation fails you are running `res.redirect` twice: First in `postEditForm` line 61 and then asynchronously in `imageEditValidation` line 57. So you are attempting to return the error after you already returned the success.

Comment: Please paste your code into your question as text and format it as code.  That way people can copy it and modify it into answers and it can be indexed for searching.  Code in images is not the way of stackoverflow.  Please insert code into questions as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `await`

`await imageEditValidation(updateHadith, images,req, res, id)`

Currently, it's not awaiting, so it's jumping to `req.flash("success", "successfully editing the Hadith")` without waiting for it to be returned.

You also need to add a `return` after `console.log(updatedHadith)

Also need to remove req.flash and res.redirect('/hadith/${id}') statement, and replace it with a `return`

Comment: yes, however even then it won't work yet because the success code isn't conditional, it runs even if the error code already run (by awaiting it, it just reverses the order in which those things happens) - there is another step needed, not running the success code when validation failed.

Answer (score 0):

the validator code will be

```
 module.exports.imageEditValidation = async (updatedHadith,images,req,) => {
    const length = updatedHadith.images.length 
    const max = 6    
    if(images.length+length <= max) {
      updatedHadith.images.push(...images) 
      await updatedHadith.save()
      console.log(updatedHadith)
      return true
    } else{
      req.flash('error','Sorry you can`t have more than 6 images')
      return false
    }
}
```

and controller code will be

```
 module.exports.postEditForm =async (req, res, next) => {
const {id} = req.params;
const updatedHadith = await HadithModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  id,
  {...req.body.Hadith},
  { runValidators: true }
);

const images = req.files.map(f => ({url : f.path ,filename: f.filename}))   
  if(await imageEditValidation (updatedHadith,images,req)){
    req.flash("success", " The Hadith is successfully Edited :)");    
  }

res.redirect(`/hadith/${id}`);
```

}